# Multiple permissions in view_config decorator?

Tags: python, web-applications, permissions, security, pyramid

I am configuring access control for a web application based on the Pyramid framework. I am setting up permissions for my view callables using the `@view_config` decorator. I have two permissions, namely `'read'` and `'write'`. Now, I want certain views to require *both* permissions. I was unable to figure out how to do this with `view_config` - am I missing something, or is there maybe another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a `readwrite` permission. Each view gets one and only one permission but each principal can be mapped to many permissions.

Comment: I guess I'll do that, then. Too bad there isn't another way. Cheers!