# pyramid authorization - customized views

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

Currently I use a simple SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch authentication setup (without using pyramid's authorization method), that is, I just raise HTTPForbidden when a user can't do something (these checks happen at various places, including when validating deform, etc.).

With a new project I want to try using pyramid's authorization method, but I'm hitting a hard wall in terms of having customized views.

## Current Understanding

1. Every view (I use the `@view_config` decorator) can have one permission string. Commonly 'read' and 'write', but can be any string, really. [Multiple permissions in view_config decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055029/multiple-permissions-in-view-config-decorator)
2. Every user can have many principals (gleaned from the [SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html))
3. The link between a principal and a permission string is the [authorization policy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html#creating-your-own-authorization-policy), which means multiple principals can have the same permission string.

This seems fairly streamlined for [the example](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html) of blog posts etc., where defining the `__acl__` allows specification of who can access a particular page, and where 'everyone can read but only these two roles can edit' makes sense.

## Bottleneck

Point 1. where every view must have one and only one permission string seems sub-optimal. The [link in point 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055029/multiple-permissions-in-view-config-decorator) is a case in point, where a 'readwrite' permission string must be used.

In particular I'd like to create a policy where users A and B are both allowed to view a particular view (a list of items), but user A can edit certain fields in that page, while user B can edit certain other fields (possibly overlapping). Methods which can achieve that now:-

1. In my form validation (or request.POST checks) I can [check if a user has permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916127/check-if-a-user-has-a-permission-in-pyramid-pylons-2).
2. In my form generation (I use deform) I can run the same checks to mark certain fields as read-only.
3. In my template I can run the same check to hide/show fields as necessary.
4. Each submit hits different URLs, with thin views which specify a particular permission string and redirect back to the original page for POST (only if the view authorization is passed).

The first 3 seem fairly clunky, in that they're exactly what I was doing before (except now I need to use `has_permission` rather than check request.user.role or request.user.id manually).

The fourth seems more 'correct' in utilizing pyramid authentication/authorization but requires a whole bunch of new URLs, routes, and views just for this purpose. Essentially lots of added complexity, which I can't just wall off in a `security.py` as I'd hoped to do by using pyramid's authorization method.

## Summary

Have I missed something in terms of how authorization can make my life easier, because all the above seem to add overhead and code complexity compared to my manual checks (which I want to get rid off because that makes authentication distributed throughout my code, in the templates, in the views, and even sometimes in the model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option: Your views are protected by a general permission specifying whether the user can view/submit the form, and then you have more granular permissions which you manually check in the code:

```
@view_config(..., permission='view-kittens')
def view_kitten(request):
    data = {}
    kitten = fetch_kitten_from_db(request.matchdict['id'])
    if request.has_permission('view-kitten-name'):
        data['name'] = kitten.name
    if request.has_permission('view-kitten-color'):
        data['color'] = kitten.color
    return data

@view_config(..., permission='edit-kittens')
def edit_kitten(request):
    kitten = fetch_kitten_from_db(request.matchdict['id'])
    if request.has_permission('edit-kitten-name'):
        kitten.name = request.POST['name']
    if request.has_permission('edit-kitten-color'):
        kitten.color = request.POST['color']
    kitten.save()
    ...
```

Another option is to have more granular set of view functions, each protected by an individual permission:

```
@view_config(..., permission='edit-kitten-name')
def edit_kitten_name(request):
    ...

@view_config(..., permission='edit-kitten-color')
def edit_kitten_color(request):
    ...
```

which probably won't play well with Deform but would be fine for some sort of AJAX frontend.

Comment: First, thanks for your quick reply! Your first suggestion looks pretty much like my point 1. on manually checking permissions, while the second suggestion requires AJAX (which I don't really want to get into for this simple project), and indeed would be crappy to implement for deform.

Comment: Well, fundamentally at the Pyramid level your question boils to "I have two actions which require different permissions and I have one view function to handle them" - the answer to this is "either check permissions manually inside the view function or have two separate view functions". I don't see how being able to assign more than one permission to a view function would help here or in what situation would it even make sense.

Comment: Re. doing checks manually - I haven't worked with Deform lately but I'm sure it is possible to write some generic function to check permissions on each field of a Colander schema on the way out (and make the widget read-only) and on the way in (to ignore the changes or throw an exception).

Comment: On the way in is trivial, on the way out less so as deform has this ridiculous (IMO) idea that an unchange-able field should not be returned when the form is submitted...

Comment: Great answer @Sergey! As far as deform goes I think you can make a deferred schema and use schema binding to generate a different schema based on the user's permissions by passing flags (or even `has_permission` directly) into the `schema.bind(..)`.